# Can't get item with lore or custom name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to give myself an item with a custom name as well as some lore. I tried `/give <my username> tripwire_hook{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Dungeon Key\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"bold\":\"true\"}",Lore:["{\"text\":\"Use in the Dungeon\",\"color\":\"dark_blue\",\"bold\":\"true\"}"]}} 1` but it says "Unknown item name: tripwire_hook{display:{Name:"{"text":"dungeon".

Does anyone know why this might be and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: which version of Minecraft are you using?

Comment: /give <name> tripwire_hook{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Dungeon Key\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"bold\":\"true\"}",Lore:["{\"text\":\"Use in the Dungeon\",\"color\":\"dark_blue\",\"bold\":\"true\"}"]}} if you are using newer versions

Comment: Please always try a shorter/simpler command first if the longer/more complex one doesn't work, then add more things back in afterwards. That either solves the problem already or at least narrows it down to the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

This command is for minecraft 1.16.1:
`/give @p tripwire_hook{display:{Name:"[{\"text\":\"dungeons key\",\"italic\":false,\"color\":\"dark_red\"}]",Lore:["[{\"text\":\"use in the dungeons\",\"italic\":false,\"color\":\"gray\"}]"]}} 1`

You could try use this command generator:  https://www.gamergeeks.nz/apps/minecraft/give-command-generator

Make sure you have selected the minecraft version you are playing in!